# Javascript - Issue using eval on a safe string containing mathematics operations

Tags: javascript

Im having a bit of an issue using eval to perform this safe operation.

```
var s = "(4.4 / 2.2) * 4567";
alert(eval(s)); // gives 9134

var t = "(4.4 / 2.2) * 04567";
alert(eval(t)); //gives 4846
```

Can someone explain to me why the 0 being appended to the 4567 on var t is causing the answer to be 4846.

Comment: [Please `"use strict"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript interprets numbers starting with a zero as octal. So 04567 in base 8 is 2423 in base 10.

You could try using a regular expression to remove the zero or an external library to parse the expression.

This would be one way for example:

```
var expression = "(4.4 / 2.2) * 04567".replace(/\d+/g, function(val){
     return parseInt(val, 10)
});
alert(eval(expression));
```

The code replaces all numbers with the base 10 version. Note that the solution would need to be modified to work for decimals or negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, prefixed 0 in numbers are consider as octal.

> The following are examples of octal numbers:
>   **01234, -077 0312**
>   **Positive octal numbers** must begin with 0 (zero) followed by octal digit(s).
>   **Negative octal numbers** must begin with -0 followed by octal digit(s).

You can overcome using

```
var t = "(4.4 / 2.2) * Number(04567)";
```